# Backbone Object render has no method apply - issue with bind

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

So I'm doing this in my AppView

```
var flowerModel = new app.DataModel({title: "flower", values: ["tulip","rose","dandelion"], dataToShow:["tulip", "rose", "dandelion"], data: data});
    var timelineModel = new app.TimeChartModel({data: flowerModel.getDisplayedData(), titlesToShow: flowerModel.get('dataToShow')});


    tableCollection.add(flowerModel);

    var timechart = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class","timechart");

    this.centerView = new app.TimeChartView({model: flowerModel, el : timechart});
    this.rightView = new app.TableView({model: flowerModel});
```

In my TimeChartView init method I do this-

```
initialize: function(){
        this.model.bind('change','render');
            //other, irrelevant things
```

}

and in my flowerModel I have this method, which works when a checkbox is ticked -

```
events: {
    'click .data-type' : 'collapseDatum',
    'click .show-datum' : 'addDatumToShow',
},

addDatumToShow: function(e){
        var test = $(this.$el).find(".datum-list").find(":checked");
        newDataToShow = [];
        _.each(test, function(value,key,list){
            var title = $(value).data("title");
            newDataToShow.push(title);
        });
        this.model.set("dataToShow", newDataToShow);
    },
```

The error happens on the this.model.set('dataToShow', newDataToShow).

I'm really not sure why and any advice on how to debug would be helpful. I don't think I'm doing anything crazy, or unusual here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
flowerModel.bind('change:dataToShow', function() { 
    timelineModel.set('titlesToShow', flowerModel.get('dataToShow')); 
});
```

---

```
this.model.bind('change', this.render);
```

Comment: sorry - I just realized that line won't matter

Comment: what's weird is that Backbone thinks that there is an object called render, as opposed to thinking we're dealing with a model, which leads me to believe this is an issue with this

Comment: yes the second part worked - so it was looking for an object called render as opposed to a function? why the weird error message?

Comment: When you call the bind function on an object, the second parameter must be a callback (function) that will be executed when the event will be triggered.

Comment: @praks5432: You're misunderstanding the error message, the "render" in the error is the value of the string you're passing to `bind` and the "Object render" stuff is just how the exception is displaying the string `'render'`.